# Validators required not working with custom validator

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation

I am creating a form to create a new user. I am using a custom validator to validate if password and confirm password field values are matching. I've made both the fields mandatory ie they can't be empty.An error is shown if the password field is empty and I try to create a user. However no error is being thrown when the confirm password field is empty.I'm still not able to create a user if the confirm password field is empty but I want the error to be shown. I don't know what to do. Please help. Thanks in advance.

This is my template:

```
<mat-form-field class="login-field-full-width margin">
    <input matInput [type]="!hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
<mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.password.hasError('required')">Password is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="login-field-full-width">
 <input matInput formControlName="passwordAgain" placeholder="Confirm password" [type]="!hideConfirmPassword ? 'password' : 'text'" [errorStateMatcher]="passwordsMatcher">                    
 <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.passwordAgain.hasError('required')">Confirm Password is required</mat-error><mat-error *ngIf="addForm.hasError('passwordsNotEqual')">Password Mismatch!</mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

My custom errorStateMatcher:

```
export class RepeatPasswordEStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return (control && control.parent.get('password').value !== control.parent.get('passwordAgain').value && control.dirty);
  }
}
export function RepeatPasswordValidator(group: FormGroup) {
  const password = group.controls.password.value;
  const passwordConfirmation = group.controls.passwordAgain.value;

  return password === passwordConfirmation ? null : { passwordsNotEqual: true };
}
```

My formGroup:

```
passwordsMatcher = new RepeatPasswordEStateMatcher;
this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      passwordAgain: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),

    }, { validator: RepeatPasswordValidator });
  }

onSubmit() {

    if (this.addForm.valid) {
      this.userService.createUser( this.addForm.value)
        .subscribe();

    }

  }
```

Comment: In this code, I'm unable to get the error when the confirm password field is left empty.

Comment: Well, I just told you that I tried your code and it works. Please replicate the issue in a stackblitz :)

Comment: Were you able to get the password required error when you left the confirm password field empty

Comment: Yes. Thus I asked for a demo :) It works on angular version 8, that I can confirm.

Comment: Strange.I'm unable to get that error.

Comment: Could it be that the fields were not touched/dirty before you try to submit them? If the fields are empty, `this.addForm.valid === false`, but the error is still not displayed because the fields are not dirty. This means that if `this.addForm.valid === false`, you have to mark the field as dirty: `this.addForm.get('username').markAsDirty()`. You can also loop over the controls and mark them all as dirty.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I have misunderstood the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error state matcher, you can listen to `form.submitted` and show validation if the form has been submitted.

Probably you do not want to show both the required message and the custom error message at the same time, so add a check for the custom validation template:

```html
*ngIf="addForm.hasError('passwordsNotEqual') && 
       !addForm.hasError('required', 'passwordAgain')"
```

Then as mentioned above add the check form `form.submitted` in the custom error state matcher:

```ts
return ((control && form.form.get('password').value !== control.value && control.dirty) 
       || form.submitted)
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvftq5-1nrrhz?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts)**

Comment: this is working but if I add another field which is mandatory, the confirm password field still throws an error even if it is non-empty and the third field is empty.

Comment: For instance when the username is empty and I try to submit,both the username and confirm password field throw error.I want that only the username field throws error if both the other fields a non-empty

Comment: please can you fork my stackblitz and show what the issue is, with steps to reproduce what you are facing

Comment: I added an additional check control.parent.get('passwordAgain').value === ' ' to the validator.Now it works as expected.Thanks a lot for your help.